# Python web scraping involving HTML a tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to scrap the names in a table from a website using bsoup script but the program is returning nothing or "[]". I would appreciate if any one can help me pointing what I'm doing wrong.
Here is what I'm trying to run:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url="http://www.trackinfo.com/entries-race.jsp?raceid=GBM$20140228E02"
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
names=soup.findAll('a',{'href':'href="dog.jsp?runnername=[^.]*'})
for eachname in names:
print eachname.string
```

And here is one of the elements that I'm trying to get:

```
<a href="dog.jsp?runnername=PG+BAD+GRANDPA">

                        PG BAD GRANDPA

                        </a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [documentation for BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), which says that if you want to give a regular expression in a search, you need to pass in a compiled regular expression.

Taking your variables, this is what you want:

```
import re
names = soup.find_all("a",{"href":re.compile("dog")})
```

Comment: +1: For linking to BS and the short and sweet answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

A different approach, this one using `Requests` instead of `urllib2`. Matter of preference, really. Main point is that you should clean up your code, especially the indentation on the last line.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import re

url = "http://www.trackinfo.com/entries-race.jsp?raceid=GBM$20140228E02"
r = requests.get(url).content
soup = bs(r)
soup.prettify()

names = soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile("dog"))

for name in names:
    print name.get_text().strip()
```

Let us know if this helps.